# How do you reset an Unreal Engine 4/5 landscape back to 0 Z height or sea level?

Tags: unreal-engine4, unreal-engine5

Changing the Z on the location of the landscape does not change the actual landscape height location.

Here are some examples to explain.

New landscape is at sea level 0
You can see this by looking at the blueprint actor Z height which when zero intersects the landscape plane.  A positive Z height on the blueprint actor moves it above and a minus for below.  This is working as expected.  The problem is when I import a certain heightmap the landscape is not at 0 even if I change the Z location to 0 for the landscape.  Again you can see the actual height location of the imported landscape by seeing the location of the blueprint actor.

New blank landscape demonstrating what the Z height the landscape should be at, look at the Z height of the blueprint actor.  This shows that the landscape is actually at zero.

[image]

When I move the blueprint actor up the Z height goes up as expected.

[image]

Now the problem is on this next picture showing the imported landscape.  In this picture you can see that the blueprint actor is at -24550.0.  This is the true height level of the landscape which should be 0.  Note in the next picture you can see that the landscape Z height is already set at 0
[image]

Picture showing landscape Z is already at 0 even though this is not the true landscape height.

[image]

So my question is how do you reset the landscape to be back at 0 height sea level even though the Z height is showing 0?  Without changing any of the landscape features.  I will need to be able to change the landscape Z scale which should only affect the sculpted features however it does seem to move the landscape.  I don't really understand that.

Comment: something like terrain's height in meters multiplyed by -1 and devided by 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A 16 bit height map has a range of -32768 to 32,768, so the "height" is determined in your height map file.  If exporting from something like World Machine then add a constant value to the heightmap before exporting.